# Meteor Blaze HTML: conditional templates inside each loop

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have 3 people, each with unique answer to the same question.

1 template shows the name and question.  Another different template holds the answer.  (4 total templates. 1 for names/question, 3 other - 1 for each unique answer).

```
<template name="people">

  {{#each profile }}

    <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ question }}</p>    

    <p>{{> answer }}</p> 

  {{/each }}

</template>
```

I want to set up a helper, so that when each `profile` loop is running, I can insert the correct named template (instead of `{{> answer }}`, 3 distinct templates identified by their name `{{> nameAnswers  }}`, aka `{{> fooAnswers  }}`.

Tried this, which displays all 3, in each `profile`, instead of 1 per `profile`.

```
<template name="people">

  {{#each profile }}

    <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ question }}</p>              

            {{#if nameHelper=Fred }}  
              {{> fredAnswers }}
            {{/if }}

            {{#if nameHelper=Ringo }}  
              {{> ringoAnswers }}
            {{/if }}  

            {{#if nameHelper=Jackson }}  
              {{> jacksonAnswers  }}
            {{/if }} 
  {{/each }}

</template>
```

Note: the `{{> nameAnswers }}` templates are already defined as static html, need to insert them is all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can to do this...

Using Blaze

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

```
<template name="people">

  {{#each profile }}

    <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ question }}</p>              

            {{#if isName Fred }}  
              {{> fredAnswers }}
            {{/if }}

            {{#if isName Ringo }}  
              {{> ringoAnswers }}
            {{/if }}  

            {{#if isName Jackson }}  
              {{> jacksonAnswers  }}
            {{/if }} 
  {{/each }}

</template>


Template.people.helpers({
    isName:function(name){
       return //true or false;
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, because the unique condition accepts is true o false. You can any operation inside the helper isName this is most the sufficient.I attach the documentation of Blaze https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

Answer (score 5):

You cannot test equality with `=` operator like that. You need to define a helper to do so, for example:

```
UI.registerHelper('equals', function(a, b) {
  return a == b; // == intentional
};
```

And then you can use it:

```
{{#if equals nameHelper 'Ringo'}}  
  {{> ringoAnswers}}
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 3):

`{{#if nameHelper=Fred }}` tests whether `Spacebars.kw({nameHelper: view.lookup("Fred")})` is true, which it is, because it's an object. That's why all three are showing up.

It looks like you have a helper, `nameHelper`, that returns a string. You could use a helper that returns a template instead. Suppose it's like this:

```
Template.people.nameHelper = function () {
    // return 'Fred', 'Ringo', or 'Jackson'
};

Template.people.chooseAnswerTemplate = function () {
    return {
        'Fred': Template.fredAnswers,
        'Ringo': Template.ringoAnswers,
        'Jackson': Template.jacksonAnswers
    }[Template.people.nameHelper.call(this)];
};
```

and in your `people` template,

```
<template name="people">
    {{#each profile }}
        ...
        {{> chooseAnswerTemplate}}
    {{/each }}
</template>
```

Comment: What affect does [Template.people.nameHelper.call(this)] have on the object with the names/templates? Thanks.

Comment: it just looks up the key `Template.people.nameHelper.call(this)`, thus returning one of those Template.????Answers values

Comment: A clearer way to include a dynamically-computed template is to use `{{> Template.dynamic template=chooseAnswerTemplate }}` - [ref](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic)